# How can I import other files in Vala?

Tags: import, vala

The question pretty much says it all- how could I import `file2.vala` to `file1.vala`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't do it directly. If you run `valac file1.vala file2.vala`, it is as if you compiled them in one big file.

If you want to make them reusable, then you probably want a shared library. In which case, you compile one to produce a C header file and a VAPI definition:

```
valac --vapi file1.vapi -H file1.h --library libfile1.so file1.vala
```

The second one can then consume this:

```
valac --pkg file1 file2.vala
```

This assume that the VAPI file has been installed. If this is not the case, you'll need to pass `--vapidir` and the location where `file1.vapi` exists, probably `.`. Similarly, you'll need to inform the C compiler about where `file1.h` lives with `-X -I/directory/containing`, again, probably `-X -I.`. Finally, you'll need to tell the C linker where `libfile1.so` is via `-X -L/directory/containing -X -lfile1`. This is a little platform specific, and you can smooth the difference out using AutoMake, though this is a bit more involved. Ragel is the usual go-to project for how to use AutoMake with Vala.

Answer (score 6):

just to supply apmasell:

you can use multiple files by using classes and public variables:

main.vala:

```
extern void cfunction(string text);

void main ()
{
    first f = new first ();
    f.say_something(f.mytext);
    cfunction("c text\n");
}
```

class.vala:

```
public class first {

    public string mytext = "yolo\n";
    public first ()
    {
        stdout.printf("text from constructer in first\n");
    }

    public void say_something(string text)
    {
        stdout.printf("%s\n", text);
    }
}
```

text.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cfunction(const char *s)
{
    puts("This is C code");
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

compiles with: `valac class.vala main.vala text.c`

as you can see, you can even use C code