# Not able to call C functions from Vala

Tags: c, import, vala

I am trying to use this [C statistics library](http://freesourcecode.net/cprojects/97697/Statistics-library-in-c#.YzhabUhBzQU) in Vala. The C file with all statistical functions are in `statlib.c`.

I used method given in a simple example given [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/vala-list/2011-May/msg00060.html).

My code is in main.vala, which is as follows:

```
extern double sum(double[] doublelist, int len); 

public static void main(string[] args){
    var numlist = {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5};
    var total = sum(numlist, numlist.length); 
    stdout.printf("The sum is %d \n", total);
}
```

However, it is producing following error:

```
$ vala main.vala statlib.c 
statlib.c:2.2-2.9: error: syntax error, invalid preprocessing directive
statlib.c:2.10-2.10: error: syntax error, expected identifier
statlib.c:3.2-3.9: error: syntax error, invalid preprocessing directive
statlib.c:4.2-4.9: error: syntax error, invalid preprocessing directive
statlib.c:5.2-5.9: error: syntax error, invalid preprocessing directive
statlib.c:6.2-6.9: error: syntax error, invalid preprocessing directive
statlib.c:634.39-634.39: error: syntax error, unexpected character
statlib.c:635.45-635.45: error: syntax error, unexpected character
statlib.c:1325.13-1325.17: error: syntax error, expected declaration
statlib.c:1325.28-1325.32: error: syntax error, expected declaration
```

Lines 2-6 in statlib.c are of include files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include "statlib.h"
```

Lines 634-636 are:

```
r = (sumxy - (sumx * sumy) / n) / \
    (sqrt((sumxsqr - (sumx * sumx) / n) \
    * (sumysqr - (sumy * sumy) / n)));
```

Line 1325 in c file is a function declaration:

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
```

Where is the problem and how can I use this C library functions in Vala?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734487/how-do-i-compile-vala-to-c-and-call-functions-in-another-file-originally-writte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compile your C code with vala here:

```
$ vala main.vala statlib.c
```

That does not work. You have to compile the C library with a C compiler (like clang or gcc), the Vala code with the Vala compiler and finally link both together with a linker.

The easiest way to do this would be something like the meson build system which will automate a lot of the steps for you.

The meson.build file could look something like this:

```
project('foo', 'c', 'vala')

bar_lib = library('bar', 'statlib.c')
bar_dep = declare_dependency(link_with: bar_lib, 
                           include_directories: include_directories('.'))

executable('foo', 'foo.vala', dependencies: [bar_dep])
```

Build with:

```
meson build
ninja -C build
```

To actually use the C code in Vala you also have to write or generate a `bar.vapi` file.

More info:

- https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tools/Meson
- https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ManualBindings
- https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Bindings

Comment: valac (or vala) is used as I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734487/how-do-i-compile-vala-to-c-and-call-functions-in-another-file-originally-writte and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734487/how-do-i-compile-vala-to-c-and-call-functions-in-another-file-originally-writte

Comment: I didn't know that valac can do that, I wouldn't use it though.