# Can valac link object files to executable

Tags: linker, executable, vala

I have 2 object files from which I want to create an executable. I see that I can do it with `gcc` as follows:

```
gcc main.vala.o statlib.o -lm -lglib-2.0
```

main.vala.o is created with valac using command `valac -c main.vala` while statlib.o is created with gcc using command `gcc -c statlib.c`.

I tried to create executable with valac but I got error with following command:

```
$ valac main.vala.o statlib.o --library=m --library=glib-2.0
error: main.vala.o is not a supported source file type. Only .vala, .vapi, .gs, and .c files are supported.
error: statlib.o is not a supported source file type. Only .vala, .vapi, .gs, and .c files are supported.
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

How can I link object files to create executable with `valac` compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `gcc` instead:

```
$ gcc -o main main.vala.o statlib.o -lm `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```

See also the meson.build file I posted in your previous question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73972038/426242

Edit: Sorry I didn't completely read you question, you already know how to use `gcc`, but still: That is the way to go.